# Show that 1/2(Tn+Mn)=T2n

Tags: calculus

Prove that:

$$\frac{1}{{2}}(T_n+M_n) = T_{2n}$$

For my question, I want to know if my proof is correct. I have a feeling I did something wrong.

[image]

Comment: For the midpoint riemann sum, since each height is the middle height, I factored out the two from each, and besides the very first point and very last point, all points in between overlap  like as in the trapezoid riemann sum

Comment: Mn becomes the same as Tn because each height is the average between the left function value and the right function value, so I factored out 1/2. Then inside the brackets, I am just left with x0 + x1 + x1 + x2+ x2 +.... + xn. As you can see these overlap so I added them up like how its shown for Tn

Comment: Given your definition of $T_n$, shouldn't you have$$T_{2n}=\frac{\Delta x}2(f(x_0)+2f(x_1)+\cdots+2f(x_{2n-1})+f(x_{2n}))?$$

Comment: n is the only last subinterval, why is it 2n?

Comment: Every instance of $n$ in $T_n$ needs to be replaced with $2n$ in $T_{2n}$. $x_0,\ldots,x_n$ are the $n$ sampling points for the trapezoidal approximation using $n$ trapezoids. $T_{2n}$ uses $2n$ trapezoids, so there should be $2n$ sampling points as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is incorrect in two places. First, it is not true in your third last line that $\displaystyle f(\bar{x_i})=\frac{f(x_{i-1})+f(x_i)}{2}$. The mean is of the *argument*, not of the function. In other words, the "midpoint" refers to the strips' width on the $x$-axis, not their height on the $y$-axis. Second, in your second last line you jump from $\big(\ldots+f(x_n)\big)$ to $\big(\ldots+f(x_{2n})\big)$ without justification. So you suddenly have twice as many terms, which can't be right. This emphasises the point of the equation you're trying to prove: as you go from $n$ to $2n$, you are doubling the number of sampling points.

---

We know that the midpoint rule takes samples at the midpoint (mean) of each strip, while the trapezium rule takes samples at the boundaries. So, considering just the $x$-axis with the sampling-points, *, and boundaries between strips, |, of a given midpoint rule, $M_n$:

```
|--*--|--*--|--*--|--*--|--*--|--*--|--*--|--*--|
```

and of a given trapezium rule, $T_n$:

```
|*----|*----|*----|*----|*----|*----|*----|*----|*
```

The sampling points don't overlap for a given $n$. You wish to show that combining these two sums into a mean gives you the *next* trapezium rule, $T_{2n}$, with twice as many strips:

```
|*--|*--|*--|*--|*--|*--|*--|*--|*--|*--|*--|*--|*--|*--|*--|*--|*
```

So you can algebraically set up your problem in a clearer way if you use *this* figure to label the indices of your points. Otherwise, you end up labelling your points twice. Note that $2n\mapsto n$ means $\Delta x \mapsto 2\Delta x$.

$$T_{2n}=\frac{\Delta x}{2}\big(f(x_0)+2f(x_1)+\ldots+2f(x_{\text{all}})+\ldots+f(x_{2n-1})+f(x_{2n})\big)
\\
T_{n}=\frac{(2\Delta x)}{2}\big(f(x_0)+2f(x_2)+\ldots+2f(x_{\text{even}})+\ldots+2f(x_{2n-2})+f(x_{2n})\big)
\\
M_{n}={(2\Delta x)}\big(f(x_1)+f(x_3)+\ldots+f(x_{\text{odd}})+\ldots+f(x_{2n-3})+f(x_{2n-1})\big)
$$

You should be able to take it from here.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. By the way, in my third last line how is it not true? I know the midpoint rule refers to the strips' width on the x-axis, so that is why I wrote the argument inside the brackets of f(), meaning that whatever inside the brackets gets evaluated first then you plug that x-value back in the function to get the function value (the midpoint value); so this is different from what you wrote.

Comment: I wrote f [ ( ((xi-1) + (xi)) / 2) ], not [ f(xi-1) + f(xi) ]/2

Comment: @Jtheconstant You correctly have the mean in the argument in the third line of your definitions but not in your algebra. You go from $\Delta x\big(f(\bar{x_1})+\ldots+f(\bar{x_n})\big)$ in the 4th last line to $\frac{\Delta x}{2}\big(f(x_0)+2f(x_1)+\ldots+f(x_n)\big)$ in the 3rd last line. This is equivalent to ${\Delta x}\big(\left[\frac{f(x_0)+f(x_1)}{2}\right]+\left[\frac{f(x_1)+f(x_2)}{2}\right]+\ldots\big)$, which is the means of the functions. This is how I understood what you were trying to do.